# How to use chinese remainder theorem to calculate k%m where m is not prime?

Tags: number-theory

How to use Chinese Remainder Theorem for solving  a%m when m is not prime,
actually i have to solve a^b %m but i know it for prime numbers,but how to solve using decomposing m into prime powers and then recombining the solution.

Comment: Please give the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think that you need to see the proof of that theorem for your application. Otherwise, it seems like a homework you want not to do

Comment: the questions is (a^b % 9) but how to solve it using prime powers i.e,a^b%3^2,i have looked up a lot but not getting all that one place hence i am bit confused

Comment: @NavneetHingankar  You know how to calculate the residue for prime powers and you know and understand the chinese remainder theorem, if I understand right. Where is the problem then ?